# Installing a python script to run from the command line

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I need to make some python utilities available to run from the command line (OSX Ventura). I've been looking over example and documentation for setup.py, but can't make any progress. Even with the simplest example possible I'm not making progress:

**directory structure:**

```
./ex
  __init__.py
  myscript.py
  setup.py
```

**myscript.py**

```
#!/usr/local/bin python3
def main():
  print('hello')
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myscript',
    version='0.1.0',
    py_modules=['myscript'],
    entry_points={
        'entry_points': [
            'scr=myscript:main',
        ],
    } )
```

I'm trying to install with various combinations of parameters:

```
pip3 install -e .
pip3 install --user .
pip3 install .
```

In each case, the new command is not found. The examples do not cover what can go wrong so I'm really lost about what to try next.

Comment: According to the content of your question, the command would be `src`. Have you tried to run `src`? -- You do not need the `__init__.py`, because in your case you have only a top-level import module and no import package at all. `__init__.py` files are meant for import packages only.

Comment: @sinoroc Yes, I tried scr and got unknown command. pip3 list shows myscript as installed, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the entry_points object needs to be in the `console_scripts` group for the installer to add the script to your path.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myscript',
    version='0.1.0',
    py_modules=['myscript'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'scr=myscript:main',
        ],
    } )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use `pyinstaller` or add a shebang (`#!`) to your file**

- **pyinstaller:**

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

This will produce an executable called `myscript` which can be run like any other. For mor on pyinstaller see: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/

- **shebang:**
  The quick fix.

Add this to the top of `myscript.py`:

```
#! /usr/env/python3

(...)  # Rest of code
```

Run it with from the command line with `./myscript.py` or `./myscript` if you rename it to remove the `.py` extension.

(Personally, I've never used `setuptools`, so I can't help you there)